# Invoking value from remote state

Tags: terraform

I have a module `cluster` that spins up a GKE cluster and associated GCS buckets.
The backend for this is a GCS bucket called `cluster_tf_state_bucket`

I have defined an output in this module

```
output "vault_storage_bucket_name" {
  value = "${google_storage_bucket.vault_storage.name}"
}
```

Once I run the code, I get the output

```
✗ terraform output
vault_storage_bucket_name = vault-storage
```

Now I have a another module `vault` and in that module I need to invoke the value of `vault_storage_bucket_name` from the other module that is using a different GCS backend bucket.

So in the main.tf of my `vault` module, Im doing something like

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12.2"
}

terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "app_tf_state_bucket"
    prefix = "vault"
  }
}
data "terraform_remote_state" "cluster_vault" {
  backend = "gcs"
  config = {
    bucket  = "cluster_tf_state_bucket"
  }
}

module "vault" {
  source                = "../../../modules/vault"
  env                   = "test"
  region                = "europe-west5"
  storage_bucket_name   = "${data.terraform_remote_state.cluster_vault.vault_storage_bucket_name}"
```

But when I run this code, I get

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 24, in module "vault":
  24:   storage_bucket_name   = "${data.terraform_remote_state.cluster_vault.vault_storage_bucket_name}"

An argument named "storage_bucket_name" is not expected here.
```

I resolved the above issue by adding the below to the `variables.tf file

```
variable "storage_bucket_name"{
  type = "string"
}
```

And now I run into the error

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 24, in module "vault":
  24:   storage_bucket_name   = "${data.terraform_remote_state.cluster_vault.vault_storage_bucket_name}"

This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
"vault_storage_bucket_name".
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Most likely you have not defined the storage_bucket_name variable in your vault module.

Comment: Thanks that resolved it. But now I get `This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
"vault_storage_bucket_name".` Would you know why ?

Comment: That is a difference in how state works in 0.12: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output values from the upstream state snapshot are exposed on `terraform_remote_state` via an attribute called `outputs`, so you need to include that in your expression:

```
  storage_bucket_name   = data.terraform_remote_state.cluster_vault.outputs.vault_storage_bucket_name
```

Note the extra `.outputs` before `.vault_storage_bucket_name`. That `outputs` attribute is a map value, so you can potentially also use the map as a whole in expressions. For example, you might want to create a [Local Value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) if you expect to be referring to those remote attributes a lot and want to simplify the references:

```
locals {
  vault_cluster = data.terraform_remote_state.cluster_vault.outputs
}

module "vault" {
  source                = "../../../modules/vault"
  env                   = "test"
  region                = "europe-west5"
  storage_bucket_name   = local.vault_cluster.vault_storage_bucket_name
}
```